# How to add an XML CDATA section using SQL xmlserialize function?

Tags: sql, xml, rpgle

For a call to a third-party API, I need to prepare some XML content to be used in the HTTP body content.

To do this, XML is generated as a result of an xmlserialize SQL function within an RPG ILE program.
Everything works fine except when it comes to managing fields with & symbol inside: in this case the third-party API rejects the request for invalid XML content, even if SQL translates `&` into `&amp;` by itself.

The SQL statement is something like this:

```
exec sql
select xmlserialize(                                                 
xmldocument(                                                         
  xmlelement(                                                        
   name "Info",                                                      
   xmlconcat(                                                        
    xmlelement(name "SedeGls"                      , :xmlGlsCodSede),
    xmlelement(name "CodiceClienteGls"             , :xmlGlsCodCli ),
    xmlelement(name "PasswordClienteGls"           , :xmlGlsPassCli),
    xmlagg(                                     
     xmlelement(                                                     
      name "Parcel",                                                 
      xmlconcat(                                                     
       xmlelement(name "CodiceContrattoGls"  , :xmlGlsCodCon       ),
       xmlelement(name "RagioneSociale"      , trim(:bor_ORAGDE)  ), 
       ...other elements here...
    )                                     
   )                                 
  )                                  
 ) as clob(1M)                       
)                                    
into :xmlData                        
from TAB_COLLI coc;
```

Now, database field bor_ORAGDE may contain invalid XML chars like `&`, but I wouldn't like to substitute these characters with others inside the database. I would rather use a CDATA section to hold this database values, in order for the result to be like this:

```
<RagioneSociale><![CDATA[my personal content & content]]></RagioneSociale>
```

Despite the many efforts and tries, I haven't found any solution yet.
Simply concatenate `<![CDATA` and `trim(:bor_ORAGDE)` and `]]>` doesn't work because the beginning < and ending > symbols are translated into their corresponding entities `&lt;` and `&gt;` , so disregarding the section.

Also, adding a ccdid(1208) to the result variable, after 'as clob(1M)' doesn't work, nor using xmltext to wrap the content.

I can't believe IBM missed such a possibility, so I assume I haven't found the answer in the redbooks yet or I am missing something here.

Does this ring any bell?

Thank you